# Add date to mysqldump command

Tags: linux, bash, mysql, uuencode

I want to have my db backed up and emailed to me (the size of my db is very small so email is not problem).  I have the following mysqldump command in a cron running weekly and it is working perfectly.

```bash
mysqldump -e --user=username --password=password database | gzip | uuencode database_name.gz | mail me@domain.com
```

All I want to do is add the current date of the backup to the gzip filename so each backup filename is unique.  I have searched here for the answer and found this:

```bash
mysqldump -e --user=username --password=password database | gzip | uuencode $(date +%Y-%m-%d)-database_name.gz | mail me@domain.com
```

But I get this error: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

I tried a different version too:

```bash
mysqldump -e --user=username --password=password database | gzip | uuencode `date +'%Y%m%d'`-database.gz | mail -s "`date +'%Y%m%d'`-database.gz mysqldump backup"  me@domain.com
```

But this also results in an error: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Any suggested solutions would be welcome.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested I found the solution:

```
mysqldump -e --user=username --password=pswd database | gzip | uuencode my-dbbackup.`date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d"`.gz | mail me@domain.com
```